# uiviewcontroller cxx_destruct crash log

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I found some crash reports from xcode organizer, the screen shots are as follower:

[image]

[image]

I have no idea what wrong was going on here? Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: I also run into same problem, One thing which I noticed is that, the controller is already deallocated, but still dealloc message is called on deallocated object. It is kind of zombie object.